# Bash: command substitution with background job

Tags: shell-script, process, background-process, command-substitution

I'm trying to fire and forget a process within a function in bash.
I'd this function to return a status corresponding to the fact the process has indeed been fired and retrieve output of the function to get the PID of the sub-process. So I wrote that:

```bsh
my_ping() {
    # ... param check which potentially return 1

    ping "$1" &
    local pid
    pid="$!"
    echo "$pid"
    return 0
}
```

When calling it with command substitution, the function blocks and never returns (it does not block outside of command substitution)

```bsh
main() {
  
  # my_ping www.google.com # does not block and print PID

  # Blocks waiting for ping to terminate
  local mp_pid
  mp_pid=$(my_ping www.google.com)
}

main "$@"
```

I don't get why the function blocks in that situation, I tried various approach (setsid, disown etc...) unsuccessfully but I just don't quite grasp what is happening. Any pointer to understand this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should redirect the output of `ping` somewhere else than its default (the pipe created by the command substitution). As long as any process still holds a reference to the writing end of that pipe, the main shell will not get an EOF and will still wait in order to get all the output from the command substitution.

e.g. for redirecting it to the original stdout of your script:

```
my_ping() {
    ...
    ping "$1" >&"$out" &
    ...
}
main() {
    exec {out}>&1
    ...
    mp_pid=$(my_ping www.google.com)
}
```