# bash -c "exec -a myProcessName ./script.sh &" doesn't send that script into backgound

Tags: bash, shell-script, background-process, exec

From a bash script, I need to start three processes and put to each of these processes a name, in order to be able to stop them in a later stop command.

```bash
# Démarrer les applications eco emploi : backend métier, backend du front (Java), et front (Angular)
demarrer_applications() {
  emit "application" "start" "init" "Démarrage des applications ecoemploi" "Soumission des scripts de démarrage"

  # Partie métier, backend Java
  log "INFO" "Demande de démarrage de l'application métier ecoemploi (Backend Java)"
  START_METIER=$(bash -c "exec -a $ECOEMPLOI_METIER_PROCESS_NAME ./submit_ecoemploi_metier_back.sh &")

  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
     emit "application" "start" "fail" "Soumission de ecoemploi backend métier échouée" "$START_METIER"
     log "ERROR" "La demande de soumision de l'application métier ecoemploi (Backend Java) a échoué : $START_METIER"
     exit $?
  fi

  # Partie front, backend Java
  log "INFO" "Demande de démarrage de l'ihm ecoemploi (Backend Java)"
  START_IHM_BACK=$(bash -c "exec -a $ECOEMPLOI_IHM_BACK_PROCESS_NAME ./submit_ecoemploi_ihm_back.sh &")

  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
     emit "application" "start" "fail" "Soumission de ecoemploi backend ihm échouée" "$START_IHM_BACK"
     log "ERROR" "La demande de soumision de l'application ihm ecoemploi (Backend Java) a échoué : $START_IHM_BACK"
     exit $?
  fi

  log "INFO" "Demande de démarrage de l'ihm ecoemploi (Front Angular)"
  START_IHM_FRONT=$(bash -c "exec -a $ECOEMPLOI_IHM_FRONT_PROCESS_NAME ./submit_ecoemploi_ihm_front.sh &")

  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
     emit "application" "start" "fail" "Soumission de ecoemploi ihm front échouée" "$START_IHM_FRONT"
     log "ERROR" "La demande de soumision de l'application ihm ecoemploi (Front Angular) a échoué : $START_IHM_FRONT"
     exit $?
  fi

  log "INFO" "Les demandes de soumission des applications ont été faites."
}
```

Summarizing that script, it attempts to run these commands:

```bash
bash -c "exec -a $ECOEMPLOI_METIER_PROCESS_NAME ./submit_ecoemploi_metier_back.sh &"
bash -c "exec -a $ECOEMPLOI_IHM_BACK_PROCESS_NAME ./submit_ecoemploi_ihm_back.sh &"
bash -c "exec -a $ECOEMPLOI_IHM_BACK_PROCESS_NAME ./submit_ecoemploi_ihm_back.sh &"
```

Where each of these submit sub-scripts have this form:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
source ecoemploi-start-stop-common.sh

cd "$ECOEMPLOI_METIER_HOME"

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   emit "application" "start" "fail" "Le répertoire d'installation de l'application métier, $ECOEMPLOI_METIER_HOME, est absent" ""
   log "ERROR" "Le répertoire d'installation de l'application métier, $ECOEMPLOI_METIER_HOME, est absent"
   exit $?
fi

./start.sh
```

here, for example, `start.sh` will start a Java 17 application:

```bash
java --add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED \
   --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED \
   --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED \
   --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED \
   --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED \
   -jar target/application-metier-et-gestion.jar
```

and `ecoemploi-start-stop-common.sh` is only here to define few directory locations and two custom functions: `emit` to send a message to a Kafka topic, and `log` to log into the console:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#
# Répertoires d'installation de l'application, et noms des processus qui vont être lancés par bash/exec
ECOEMPLOI_HOME="/home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france"
ECOEMPLOI_METIER_HOME="$ECOEMPLOI_HOME/metier-et-gestion/ApplicationMetierEtGestion"
ECOEMPLOI_IHM_FRONT_HOME="$ECOEMPLOI_HOME/web-client/ApplicationEtude/etude"
ECOEMPLOI_IHM_BACK_HOME="$ECOEMPLOI_HOME/web-client/ApplicationEtude"

ECOEMPLOI_METIER_PROCESS_NAME="ecoemploi_backend_metier"
ECOEMPLOI_IHM_BACK_PROCESS_NAME="ecoemploi_ihm_backend"
ECOEMPLOI_IHM_FRONT_PROCESS_NAME="ecoemploi_ihm_front"

# Communication avec Kafka
KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER_PORT=9092
BOOTSTRAP_SERVER="localhost:$KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER_PORT"
TOPIC_VIE="ecoemploi-statut"

# Logger un message, horodaté
# $1 Sevérité
# $2 Message
log() {
   TIMESTAMP=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

   if [ "$1" = "ERROR" ]; then
      echo "$TIMESTAMP [$1] $2" >&2
   else
      echo "$TIMESTAMP [$1] $2"
   fi
}

# Emettre un évènement dans le $TOPIC_VIE de Kafka
# $1 : Composant
# $2 : Phase : init, start
# $3 : Statut : start, fail
# $4 : description
# $5 : Message
emit() {
# Laisser la ligne ci-dessous non indentée pour que EOF fonctionne.
MESSAGE_EMIT_KAFKA=$(cat << EOF
{
   "composant": "$1",
   "phase": "$2",
   "statut": "$3",
   "description": "$4",
   "message": "$5"
}
EOF
)

  MESSAGE_EMISSION_VERS_KAFKA=$(echo "$MESSAGE_EMIT_KAFKA" | kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list $BOOTSTRAP_SERVER --topic $TOPIC_VIE)

  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    log "WARN" "Le message vers le topic $TOPIC_VIE n'a pu être émis : $MESSAGE_EMISSION_VERS_KAFKA"
  fi
}
```

---

My problem is that in my bash function `demarrer_applications()`, called after few other ones and producing the last [INFO] log,

```bash
2023-04-14 10:01:09 [INFO] Démarrage de Zookeeper puis de Kafka...
2023-04-14 10:01:09 [INFO] Zookeeper et Kafka ont démarré.
2023-04-14 10:01:10 [INFO] Le topic ecoemploi-statut existant sera réutilisé sur Kafka localhost:9092.
2023-04-14 10:01:11 [INFO] Postgresql n'est pas démarré. Démarrage en cours...
2023-04-14 10:01:13 [INFO] Postgresql est prêt.
2023-04-14 10:01:14 [INFO] Demande de démarrage de l'application métier ecoemploi (Backend Java)
```

do run the wished application, with the command:

```bash
bash -c "exec -a $ECOEMPLOI_METIER_PROCESS_NAME ./submit_ecoemploi_metier_back.sh &"
```

but the `&` after the `./submit_ecoemploi_metier_back.sh` doesn't send that application into the background. And my main script cannot to continue its work and launch the following applications next. It hangs here, waiting for a Ctrl-C.

How shall I submit my `submit_ecoemploi_*.sh` scripts, in the background, with `bash` and `exec` commands? Thanks a lot!

---

@StéphaneChazelas

I used your solution to adapt my function (I only put here the changed lines):

```bash
demarrer_applications() {
  # Partie métier, backend Java
  NAME=$ECOEMPLOI_METIER_PROCESS_NAME bash -c 'exec -a "$NAME" ./submit_ecoemploi_metier_back.sh &'

  NAME=$ECOEMPLOI_IHM_BACK_PROCESS_NAME bash -c 'exec -a "$NAME" ./submit_ecoemploi_ihm_back.sh &'

  NAME=$ECOEMPLOI_IHM_FRONT_PROCESS_NAME bash -c 'exec -a "$NAME" ./submit_ecoemploi_ihm_front.sh &'
}
```

it submits perfectly, and I my application see its three components started and is useable.

but a `ps -f` returns me that:

```
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
lebihan   309213  309207  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
lebihan   322835    2710 21 11:26 pts/0    00:00:04 java -Xmx1G -Xms1G -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:Ma
lebihan   324800    2710  0 11:27 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash /home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/submit_ecoemploi_metier_back.sh
lebihan   324803    2710  0 11:27 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash /home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/submit_ecoemploi_ihm_back.sh
lebihan   324804  324800  0 11:27 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./start.sh
lebihan   324806  324803  0 11:27 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./start.sh
lebihan   324808  324804 99 11:27 pts/0    00:00:47 java --add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --
lebihan   324809    2710  0 11:27 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash /home/lebihan/dev/Java/comptes-france/submit_ecoemploi_ihm_front.sh
lebihan   324811  324806 52 11:27 pts/0    00:00:07 java --add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --
lebihan   324812  324809  0 11:27 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./start.sh
lebihan   324814  324812 51 11:27 pts/0    00:00:07 ng serve
lebihan   325316  309213  0 11:27 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -f
```

And I don't see the process names changed.
Then the stop command isn't able to stop the `submit_ecoemploi_ihm_front.sh`, `submit_ecoemploi_ihm_back.sh`, `submit_ecoemploi_metier_back.sh`

Comment: Probably it's not about sole commands; it's about command substitutions. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218515/108618) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/673248/108618).

Comment: Please don't go [chameleon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/355310).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I only added the result of what Stéphane suggested me, to show the limit of his solution that covers almost all the question, but not the part about renaming processes. My question has not changed a bit.

Comment: Yeah… Because instead of an [mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/10765659) that presents one problem, you posted a non-minimal script and apparently expect us to debug the whole of it. Background processes blocking the main script and names not being changed are two distinct problems and should be posted as two questions.

Comment: No, I had to explain why I was using `exec -a` and `bash -c` together, to avoid being suggested to remove the `exec -a`, or obtain another response that would not do the renaming of the processes currently expected.

Answer (score 4):

```
output=$(cmd &)
```

Collects the output of the subshell that runs the `cmd &` code via a pipe; all the processes started within that subshell inherit that pipe as their stdout whether they're started asynchronously or not.

The shell will read from the other end of that pipe to make up the expansion until it reaches end-of-file on that pipe which will happen only when all the  file descriptors (by any process) open on the writing end of the pipe have been closed, so typically when all the processes have died.

In any case, you can't capture the output of those processes if you return before they have output it.

You can close stdout in those processes started asynchronously there to release the fd open on that pipe if you don't need the rest of the output.

For instance:

```
output=$(sh -c 'echo some output; sleep 1; exec>&-; sleep 120' &)
```

Will return after 1 second instead of 121, leaving `sh` and `sleep 120` running in background after stdout has been closed.

Better than `exec>&-` would be to use `exec>/dev/null` which would also close the fd to the pipe, but avoid leaving stdout closed which is a bad idea in general as applications usually expect it to be opened.

If you want to capture the output of several commands running concurrently, you can't do that with variables and command substitution. In bash which doesn't have support for `select`/`poll` like functionality, best would be to use temporary files:

```
exec -a name1 cmd1 > "$temp1" &
exec -a name2 cmd2 > "$temp2" &
exec -a name3 cmd3 > "$temp3" &
wait
output1=$(<"$temp1")
output2=$(<"$temp2")
output3=$(<"$temp3")
```

(assuming bash).

No need for those `bash -c ...` here, and btw those:

```
bash -c "exec -a $ECOEMPLOI_METIER_PROCESS_NAME ./submit_ecoemploi_metier_back.sh &"
```

Are wrong as the contents of that `ECOEMPLOI_METIER_PROCESS_NAME` ends up being interpreted as bash code which is not what you want. You want is to be taken as the argument to `-a`, so it should be:

```
NAME=$ECOEMPLOI_METIER_PROCESS_NAME bash -c '
  exec -a "$NAME" ./submit_ecoemploi_metier_back.sh &'
```

Or maybe:

```
bash -c '"$@" &' bash exec -a "$ECOEMPLOI_METIER_PROCESS_NAME" ./submit_ecoemploi_metier_back.sh
```

But those `bash -c` are completely superfluous if that's a bash script. Just do:

```
exec -a "$ECOEMPLOI_METIER_PROCESS_NAME" ./submit_ecoemploi_metier_back.sh &
```

In any case, if you run a `script.sh`  with a `#! /bin/bash` shebang (so the `.sh` suffix is misleading, use `.bash` or no suffix) as `exec -a name ./script.sh arg`, the shell will do a `execve("./script.sh", ["name", "arg"], env)`, but as that's a script, on Linux at least, that will in turn run `execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "./script.sh", "arg"], env)`, and the `name` will be lost.

You can use:

```
exec -a name bash ./script.sh
```

In which case `ps -f` will show `name ./script.sh`. Beware that `bash` can adjust its behaviour based on the `argv[0]` it receives. For instance, if invoked with a `argv[0]` of `sh` or ending in `/sh`, it will enable its POSIX mode.

Or:

```
BASH_ENV=./script.sh exec -a name bash -c ''
```

In which case `ps -f` will show `"name -c "`, but beware that `BASH_ENV` will end up in the environment and mean `script.sh` will be sourced any time another bash script (including the `bash -c inline` ones) is started by `script.sh` likely causing infinite recursion.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helps to "unlock" the submission of processes. But they aren't renamed. I've added on the bottom of my opener post, the result of what your solution did.

Comment: @Marc, see edit.

Comment: Thanks for these explanations and warnings. I'm now convinced that attempting to rename processes isn't a clever idea, in my case where each application started pass through many subprocesses that, then, would have to be also renamed. An hard way.

Answer (score 1):

What you have described *mostly works* for me. I had to change a little part though. Here's my worked example:

First, the contents of `script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ -f /tmp/script.run ]       # Run only while this file exists
do
    date >/tmp/script.date 2>&1    # Update the output file
    sleep 0.5                      # Pause briefly
done
rm -f /tmp/script.date
```

Now we'll run it in the way you suggest,

```
touch /tmp/script.run
bash -c "exec -a myProcessName ./script.sh & "
```

Let's look at the process tree with `ps -f`

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
roaima    9301  9296  0 09:41 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
roaima    9913     1  0 09:46 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash /home/roaima/script.sh
roaima    9919  9913  0 09:46 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 0.5
roaima    9920  9301  0 09:46 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -f
```

You can see that the process is running (PIDs 9913 and 9919) but the process name has not been applied. That's because it's a script, and the script is executed by the process listed on its `#!` line.

Let's stop the process, wait a moment, and try again with a different approach

```
rm -f /tmp/script.run    # Remove the flag file
ps -f                    # Confirm the process has ended

touch /tmp/script.run
bash -c "exec -a myProcessName bash ./script.sh & "
```

This time the explicit invocation of `bash` has been renamed as expected:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
roaima    9301  9296  0 09:41 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
roaima   11745     1  2 09:53 pts/0    00:00:00 myProcessName ./script.sh
roaima   11777 11745  0 09:53 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 0.5
roaima   11778  9301  0 09:53 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -f
```

But actually you might as well avoid the outer invocation of `bash` and just call `exec` directly,

```
exec -a myProcessName bash ./script.sh &
```

Finally, I'd suggest that a better way to keep track of your processes is not by process name but by PID:

```
./script.sh &
scriptPID=$!

kill -0 $scriptPID && echo "The script is still running with PID $scriptPID"
```

Remove the flag file `/tmp/script.run`, pause a moment, and then repeat the `kill … && echo …` command. You'll have no output because the script is no longer running.

Comment: if a `start.sh` keep the pid of a process, how a `stop.sh` script, later run by the user, will know the pid of the process that `start.sh` learned?

Comment: Your start script writes the PID to a file in a well known location. This is standard stuff. `systemd` does it really well; have you considered using it to manage your services?

Comment: systemd could be a good idea, I didn't tough about, yes. Because my script was intended to start an application in development mode, I didn't wanted to go too far, but if solutions that I've first believed to be simple, aren't (each application looks creating many processes (2 or 3)) then systemd can be a good alternative, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to what roaima wrote about the well-known location:

```
  # Initialize a file for collecting background process numbers:
    sync_file=/tmp/syncfile.123
    printf ""  > $sync_file
    # Repeat this block for all your parallel commands:
    # This can be a loop or a fixed number of process submissions
       # Run your command(s) in a sub-shell:
       (
        # Name your process using a single word:
        pname=MyProcess.1
        # Save the name and PID of the bg process 
        printf "$pname:$?\n" >> $sync_file
        # run your command(s)
        my_command
       ) &
    # End block
    
    # This part can be run in a separate script:
    # Kill your processes using PID list you have stored in the file
    sync_file=/tmp/syncfile.123
    for a in $( cat $sync_file )
    do
        procname=${a%:*}  # Get the process name 
        pid=${a#*:}       # Get the PID
        echo "Process: $procname PID: $pid"
        kill -9 $pid
    done
```

Comment: Consision is OK, but explaination would be welcomed.

Comment: Thanks @Archemar for your comment, now I added some descriptions